# Does a recursive function require a return value outside the if statement

Tags: function, c++11, recursion, return

My code goes something like this:

```
string my_function(string input)
{
 if (sentinel reached)
  {
   return output;
  }
 else
 {
  //do something to change the string and get closer to the sentinel
  my_function(input);
 }
}
```

As you can see it is a recursive function that checks if a sentinel value has been reached at which point it returns the output of the function. If it hasn't, it performs some manipulation on the string, then executes itself in recursion.

Since I have a return function in the if statement, and the function will always get to that point, do I need a return after the else statement. It seems unnecessary since that return statement will never execute.

Comment: You should `return my_function(input)` to pipe output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You *do* need a `return` clause, but it should be `return my_function(input)` within the `else` branch otherwise the final result obtained when the sentinel is reached will not be available as the stack is unwound back to the original call.

Comment: So you're saying that the recursive action is done through the return statement?

Comment: @AhmadSiddiqui `return` will only take the value, perhaps from the result of `my_function(input)` as the result of the current function. The recursion happens no matter what, but it's dead code as you don't use the value without either passing it, returning it or assigning it.

Answer (score 1):

If you programmed the recursion well enough so that the sentinel eventually
is reached, then *some* call to this function will get to the "if" branch
of the "if" statement.

But if the function actually needed recursion, that is, if the sentinel
was not already true before *the very first time* this function was called,
then the first call to the function will execute the "else" clause and then
... what? The function is supposed to return something, but you don't
say what to return.

The fact that during the recursion in the "else" clause, some *other* 
(recursive) call to this same function executed the "if" clause,
does not tell the first call to the function what to do. It can only do
what you literally told it to.

**Edit:** The code will compile, but it will not return a meaningful value
if even one level of recursion occurs. Your compiler might issue a warning
about the lack of the return value, which you should heed.

Comment: C++ code allows functions to not return values, so the code will compile, though the behavior is undefined.

Comment: @templatetypedef You're right, and I have edited the answer accordingly.